# Cycles Taking 2 Hours to Render One Frame

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, lighting

I am new to rendering with cycles (I usually just use internal), and am trying to render a particular scene with it. The scene does include an explode particle system and a smoke system, however they are still quite simple. Though I believe there must be something wrong with my setup, as it is taking about ***2 hours*** just to render one frame at a time.
I have tried using GPU rather than CPU but it caused an error ("OpenCL build failed") so I ignored that option.

***Computer details -***

*AMD A10-7300 Radeon R6, 10 Compute Cores 4C +6G 1.90 GHz*

*8.00 GB RAM*

*64 Bit Operating System*

*Windows 10*

[image: Render Settings 1]

[image: Render Settings 2]

Any suggestions will be gratefully appreciated!

Michael.

Comment: Without seeing your settings it will be hard to help. Is square samples ticked on under the sampling settings?

Comment: Give more information, screenshots or a link tot he blend.  There is not enough information here.

Comment: How do I add a link to the blend file?

Comment: @Michael.66 https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Maybe you should mention in your post that you are trying to render at 2500 samples, with multiple explode modifiers, particles, smoke simulations with high subdivisions, etc... if you include details like on your question along with the kind of computer you are using, you might even get some satisfactory answers

Comment: @Michael.66 There is no need for that here... people volunteer their time to help others, nobody is attacking you. What he means is that your scene is computationally heavy so it will take longer to render naturally. Simulations by themselves can bring a powerful PC to a crawl. AMD GPU and Windows 10 still don't go a long way to helping either. Be *as specific* as possible (what version of Blender, what model GPU, processor, what render settings) and you will in most cases get the best answer there is.

Comment: When you use square samples you are multiplying the number of samples by itself. 50 samples squared turns into 50x50 =2500 samples (that will take a while to render) Each time you explode something you are creating more geometry, the more geometry the longer it will take to render. By exploding multiple times you are subdividing exponentially (as each of the previous subdivisions gets further subdivided)=longer rendering time.... Smoke simulations... those use more resources and take time to compute. 8gb of RAM? not a lot when the computer runs out of ram it will use disk cache (slower).

Comment: 3D rendering can get computationally intense very quickly. While computers have become more powerful, it is still quite easy to create scenes that are larger than the resources available.

Comment: Okay, so do you suggest that I not use sqaure samples?

Comment: Don't use square samples or reduce the number of samples. I was able to render your scene without square samples enabled and smoke simulated to frame 14 in 18 minutes on an 8 core 2Ghz laptop. Also, I cannot figure out why your smoke is so computationally intensive.. that is the real cause for slow render times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should turn off "Square Samples" unless you actually intend to square the number of samples being used (e.g., see https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?342753-Square-Samples for some insight into why you might want to square the samples).  For previewing purposes, you definitely want to turn it off.  And you'll probably want to bake the simulation so it doesn't have to calculate it every time you switch to a different animation frame.